# Enviar una cadena como parámetro de una función

Tags: c, string

Mi código es el siguiente

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void pasar_cadena(char cadena1);

main(){

    char cadena1 [10] = "Hola";

    pasar_cadena(cadena1); //-> Aqui es el error

}

void pasar_cadena(char cadena1 [] ){

    printf("La Cadena es: ",cadena1);

}
```

Me marca un error en la función `pasar_cadena(cadena1)`:

> invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

Alguien me podría explicar como se pasa un parámetro tipo cadena a una función de forma correcta?

He buscado en Internet y la mayoría son tipo entero o solo un carácter.

Comment: ¿ Podrías indicar el error que te marca ? Para completar la pregunta y que sea fácil de encontrar :-)

Comment: El error es el siguiente:
invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para pasar un arreglo como parametro a una funcion en c lo que esta en realidad obtiene es un puntero apuntando al primer elemento del array, no se puede pasar directamente, por lo que te dejo como es la forma correcta en base a tu ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void pasar_cadena(char const *cadena1);

main(){
   char cadena1[10] = "Hola";

   pasar_cadena(cadena1);
}

void pasar_cadena(char const *cadena1){
  printf(cadena1);
}
```

Comment: Me funcionó, Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

existen 2 problemas en tu codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void pasar_cadena(char cadena1);

main(){

    char cadena1 [10] = "Hola";

    pasar_cadena(cadena1); //-> Aqui es el error

}

void pasar_cadena(char cadena1 [] ){

    printf("La Cadena es: ",cadena1);

}
```

1: Los prototipos de las funciones se deben definir con el mismo tipo de datos que tiene la funcion, por lo tanto:

```
void pasar_cadena(char cadena1)
```

debes cambiarlo a por:

```
void pasar_cadena(char cadena1[])
```

o simplemente por:

```
void pasar_cadena(char[])
```

2: El uso de la función `printf` es incorrecto:

```
printf("La Cadena es: ",cadena1)
```

debes cambiarlo a por:

```
printf("La Cadena es [%s]\n: ",cadena1)
```

esa es la razón por la cual no sale nada en pantalla.